# dojo template add/remove child

Tags: dojo

I am using a template for popover.
I have 3 content panes within my template html.
Each content pane has widgets.
I need to hide/show content pane based on some logic.
In the `setValues` method I am able to remove the tabs, but I need to add them back in destroy method which is not working i.e. nothing happens and they continue to be removed.
How to do it? Visibility/style does not work on the content pane.
My code:

```
setValues:
var tabContainer = dijit.byId(this.id + "_tab");
            var tab2 = dijit.byId(this.id + "_SQLID2");
            var tab3 = dijit.byId(this.id + "_SQLID3");
            // Removing it:
            tabContainer.removeChild(tab2);
            tabContainer.removeChild(tab3)

  destroy:
  var tabContainer = dijit.byId(this.id + "_tab");
            var tab2 = dijit.byId(this.id + "_SQLID2");
            var tab3 = dijit.byId(this.id + "_SQLID3");
            tabContainer.addChild(tab3);
            tabContainer.addChild(tab2)

html:
 <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" persist="true" style="width: 410px;left:6px;   height:320px;" id="${id}_tab">
<!-- Tab 1-->
                            <label for="${id}_SQLID1"></label></td>
            <div dojoType="ContentPane" for="${id}_SQLID1"    id="${id}_SQLID1" name="${id}_SQLID1" value="11"class="xwtNotification" title="SQL 1">


<!-- Tab 2-->
<div dojoType="ContentPane" for="${id}_SQLID2" id="${id}_SQLID2" name="${id}_SQLID2" class="xwtNotification" title="SQL 2">

<!-- Tab 3-->
<div dojoType="ContentPane" for="${id}_SQLID3" id="${id}_SQLID3" name="${id}_SQLID3" class="xwtNotification" title="SQL 3">
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. If your widget is being destroyed, why would you want to add tabs back into it. I think the result you are getting (them continuing to be not visible/removed) is the correct behavior for a widget that is being destroyed. Maybe you can set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem as well. That would help us to diagnose the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks. I need to show/hide tabs depending upon some logic. So at a time I may have to show 1 or more tabs. However as you mentioned once I remove it, I am unable to add it back. The problem with visibility is that the content (or widgets) within the tab are hidden (so I get blank) but the tab itself is not removed. so I get a tab which has empty content. I need to hide the tab as well.

Answer (score 1):

This had me going for a while, too. Here's what I figured out:

You need to remove the tab (ContentPane) from it's tabContainer **AND** destroy the ContentPane - otherwise attempting to create a new ContentPane with the same ID will throw an error.

Remove the tab from the tabContainer with dijit.removeChild() like this:

```
dijit.byId("myTabContainer").removeChild(dijit.byId("myContentPane"));
```

Then destroy the orphaned ContentPane with:

```
dijit.byId("myContentPane").destroy();
```